# How to subclass when creating an object indirectly

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'd like to add some functionality to the html trees coming from lxml.

Thus I thought to add a class, using `super().__init__()` and add the extra functionality, such as adding the depth to each node, adding a boolean for `isLeafNode`, and implementing a `view` method.

That's where the problem starts, as I would probably initialize the lxml class by using `lxml.html.fromstring('<p>test</p>')`.

This is what I got so far:

```
class Elhanced(lxml.etree._ElementTree): 
    def __init__(self, htmlString): 
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 'useful'   
        self.tree = lxml.html.fromstring(htmlString)   # Issue

    def useful_function():
        pass
```

However, I actually want the object to be the enhanced 
lxml object with added functionality, not the tree to be accessible through `self.tree`, while the other attributes are accessible at `self`.

How can I add the functionality to the enhanced lxml object?

I'd like to initialize like this:

```
el = Elhanced('<p>test</p>')
```

where `el` has all the methods of `lxml` (such as `el.xpath` should exist), as well as `el.useful_function()` and `el.x`.

Perhaps there is even a better way that I'm not seeing at this point.

Comment: Perhaps `super().__init__()` isn't doing what you expect it to do; you can access the superclass by using `super(Elhanced, self)`. So for instance, to call `__init__()` you would use `super(Elhanced, self).__init__()`.

Comment: @Quintus in python3, `super()` should just work fine. It just has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use a wrapper class? Or if it's a single function you want to add, just call it from there: `useful_function(el, arg1, arg2)`.

Comment: @deets You're absolutely right; thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use inheritance - there is no need to worry about maintaining an agregate `self.tree` instance: your subclass will just have the behavior of the original superclass wherever you don't override it.

The only non-straightforward part is exactly that for some whatever reason, the lxml library is designed to make it hard for you to feed it a simple string to parse (and thus provide the external `fromstring` factory).

The parsing can be done if you call the instance `parse` method with a  file-like object - so you have to convert your plain string to that before calling `parse`. And yes, it can be done inside `__init__` . Just try it this way:

```
import lxml.etree
# Python 2/3 compatibility
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

class Elhanced(lxml.etree._ElementTree): 
    def __init__(self, htmlString): 
        super(Elhanced, self).__init__()
        self.x = 'useful'   
        self.parse(StringIO(htmlString), lxml.etree.HTMLParser())

    def useful_function():
        pass
```

Comment: Wow this is very awesome! Thanks so much: I had already given up hope. I edited the final bits (also a parenthesis was missing).